# Auto scaling of group instance based on memory usage in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've set up an instance group with autoscaling based on CPU utilisation
I want to set up autoscaling based on RAM utilisation.

I want to set up an instance group with load balancing based on CPU and RAM usage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (because I didn't test) you can achieve that by using a Stackdriver metric. For that, you need to [install the Cloud Monitoring agent on your servers](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/monitoring/installation).

Then you can set up an instance group with a CPU utilisation and add a new metric, and select the memory usage metric

[image]